# on a proof of the Primitive Element Theorem in zero characteristic

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Here is a version of the Primitive Element Theorem and a proof in [Fulton's Algebraic Curves](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf):

[image]

**Question:** My interpretation of the notation $(H,F)=(T-x) \in K'[T]$ is that the greatest common divisor (gcd) of $H$ and $F$ is $T-x$. Now the $gcd(a,b)$ in a principal ideal domain can be written as a linear combination of $a,b$ with coefficients inside that domain. My only concern about the present context, is that $gcd(H,F)$ may be $1$ inside the domain $K'[T]$, even though i do see that it must be $T-x$, when the coefficients are allowed to be inside a splitting field of $H,F$. So i don't understand what is the underlying argument in the proof above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that $(H,F)$ means $\gcd (H,F)$.

As for your concern: $H$ and $F$ possess $x$ as the only common zero in an algebraic closure (or any splitting field of $H$ and $F$). Then the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $K^\prime$ must divide both $H$ and $F$, hence $\gcd(H,F)\neq 1$. Does that help?

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks.